# Postgres with Ruby on Rails concept

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on Rails and databases. I am currently working on a project on Ruby on Rails with Postgresql. 
I have some concept which I do not quite understand. 
Suppose I git clone a repository which contains a Ruby on Rails project, it contains all the database and records.

And I want to run the project in development locally to make modifications. So do I have to create a database locally and change the username, password, host in the project's database.yml file? 
Or can I just run rails server and visit localhost:3000 without modifying anything?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases the database is not included when you clone a project.

Rails by default is setup to use SQLite which is a simplified database which stores the DB as a file. SQLite in Rails is just plug and play provided that your OS has sqlite installed.  However dev/test databases should not be checked into source control, instead you would use the seeds file.

Databases like Postgres run as a service on your computer or a remote server. Your app connects to the database via the port that the DB responds to or a unix socket. You can configure the settings in `config/database.yml`.

Comment: In general you only ever really want to check in application code. Never data or configuration settings.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. So does that mean that each contributor of the same project will probably have different database.yml settings such as username, password, and host?

Comment: Also, if I have a project called myApp, is the following setup correct?
database: myApp_development
pool: 100
host: localhost
username: <myusername>
password: <mypassword>

Comment: There is no way for me to know what db settings you have. In most rails projects `database.yml` is checked into source control. However a good practice is to use ENV vars so that developers don't need to match the settings.